# The time of getting in and off

Tags: word-usage

I want to describe the evaluation of my Android app (Bus tracker).

> Can I say about the time of enter and exit the bus **The time of getting in and off** since the bus was not always accurate or I should use **departure and arrival time**?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to describe. Travelling by bus involves several stages including:

> getting **on** the bus
>   getting **off** the bus
>   the bus **departing** its origin
>   and the bus **arriving** at its **destination**.

**Departure** and **arrival** describe the state of the bus.
**Getting on** and **getting off** the bus describe the state of the rider.

> What time does the bus **get in**?

Is colloquial for

> When will the bus arrive?

but is usually used in conversation.

**Arrival time** and **departure time** refer to when the bus **gets in** and when it **leaves**.
**Anticipated** or **expected** can be used as modifiers:

> **anticipated** arrival time
>   **expected** departure time